# how to show 5 bootstrap modal popups at the same time on web page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I want to create something like the below description.

I have a button that I want to open five bootstrap modal popups with some data when someone clicks on that button. and I want to show those five modals on one page, separately, without overlapping each other. Is that something that I can achieve using bootstrap modal popups? Or if there's any other better solution, then please submit your answers.

Comment: Please see [ask]. What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? Your question should be more specific.

Comment: I will say that this seems like a poor UX. It will be visually messy, with lots of wasted space for gaps, modal controls, etc. Every modal would need to be closed, either manually or programmatically. Why not a single modal with five sections?

Comment: Open 1 popup and design your 5 sections with **tabs** or **accordion** in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#toggle-between-modals) about modal components states this:

> **Please note multiple modals cannot be open at the same time**

Additionally, as other people mentioned in the comments, multiple open modals would be bad UX for a web application.